# SQL: Updating table within a table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can you update the value inside of a table that is within another table?

Say you have a table called `ratings` that has this structure:

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| video_id | user_id | rating |
+----------+---------+--------+
|      5   |   158   |    4   |
|      5   |  5875   |    1   |
|      5   |   585   |    5   |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

How could you update the value of the second row of rating? So to change the second row of rating from 1 to say.. 12.

How do you even select that value?

EDIT: It turns out I had misunderstood the situation. Instead of the columns containing variables, there was a separate column containing values which I wanted to change depending on the other columns.

Comment: Hint . . . `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where "table within a table" comes into play... It looks like a standard `update` to me.

```
update ratings
set rating = 12
where video_id = 5
  and user_id  = 5875
```

Comment: Okay, I made a simplified example but I guess it does not fully describe the situation. In my case, the values within the columns are variables that store values. So I say rating contains var1, var2 and var3 and I want to know what var2 is and update it.

Comment: @Mr.Kaplan You're going to have to update your question and be more specific about regarding schema and data types as well as the operations you are trying to perform.

Comment: Okay, it turns out I had an imperfect understanding of the table I was working with. To go back to my original example, rating contained var1, var2, var3 and there was another column called value that contained values. So what I wanted was almost exactly the answer you gave! My final solution was essentially: update ratings set value = 12 where rating=var2.

Comment: @Mr.Kaplan Glad you got to where you were trying to go!